# IntelliJ IDEA - no implementations found

Tags: intellij-idea

My IntelliJ suddenly stopped finding implementations when using Go To Implementation. And it's happening with all projects I tried. I'm looking for some clues about what settings to check or how to solve that.

Comment: Restart application/pc and try again

Comment: I tried that already, invalidating cache also.

Comment: Please review your installed third-party plugins: sometimes they can influence negatively on such functionality. Particularly I was having similar issues with `jd-idea` plugin.

Comment: yep, uninstalling `sql code assistant` helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @n1ckolas in the comments:

You should review your installed third-party plugins because sometimes
they can influence negatively on such functionality. It is likely that this is the case in your situation.